# JarOutputStream creating a 'bad' jar

Tags: jar

http://pastebin.com/qrSCZw3y

I made that so I can create jars whenever I want by doing:

```
Builder jarBuilder = new Builder("jarname.jar");
jarBuilder.createNewFile();
```

But, whenever I do that, it creates a jar, and when I click on the jar, I get this message:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jWem.png

I want the generated jar to say something like "Hello world" or whatever I define.

Please help me, as I've searched all across the internet, but there were no video tutorials, and the documentations that I found online didn't help me much either.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know how to create a .jar file, but I don't know how to make it have custom settings user defined from my jframe.